# Is there any other way to connect VPC endpoints cross-region without using ELBs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

we are planning to create vpcendpoint in us-west-2 for nlb in us-east-1, for that currently we created nlb in us-west-2, created target groups pointing to to us-east-1 nlb interface ips and create VPC endpoint to the nlb in us-west-2. This setup works fine.
However, looking for better alternatives.
The nlb in east targets alb in the same region.

Answer (score 1):

> However, looking for better alternatives.

Using [Route 53 resolvers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resolver.html) to route cross-region traffic may be a better, simpler alternative to using ELBs.

From [AWS guide](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/using-vpc-endpoints-in-multi-region-architectures-with-route-53-resolver/):

> The challenge some customers have faced is that VPC endpoints can only be used to access resources in the same Region as the endpoint

> One of the ways we can solve this problem is with Amazon Route 53 Resolver. Route 53 Resolver provides inbound and outbound DNS services in a VPC. It allows you to resolve domain names for AWS resources in the Region where the resolver endpoint is deployed. It also allows you to forward DNS requests to other DNS servers based on rules you define. To consistently apply VPC endpoint policies to all traffic, we use Route 53 Resolver to steer traffic to VPC endpoints in each Region.

---

In-built to AWS PrivateLink, cross-region requests are still not supported (read this for [S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpc-endpoints-s3.html) and this for [DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpc-endpoints-ddb.html)) so there's no configuration possible on that front.